# Ошибка Yii2 (web framework)

Tags: php, css3, html5, веб-программирование, yii2

Использую Yi2 (web framework), в качестве локального сервера использую openServer. Развернул базу данных в phpmyadmin, выходит следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что именно вам не ясно в тексте?

Comment: Что делать в данной ситуации?

Comment: использовать другую версию php или другую новую версию фреймворка

Comment: какая у вас версия фреймворка? А php?

Comment: При использовании PHP более устарелой версии возникает ошибка 502

Comment: php 8 версия, yii 2.0.14.2 версия

Answer (score 0):

`getClass` устарела начиная с *PHP8.0*. Вариантов не много:

1. В самом ядре фреймворка поменять `->getClass()` на `->getType()->getName()`

   Проблема будет возникать, если придётся обновлять фремворк.
2. Понизить версию языка php на 7.0 и около оной
3. Установить уровень вывода ошибок на пониже, т.е. не выводить предупреждения уровня `DEPRECATED`. Это тоже не очень, если в дальнейшем захотите что-то улучшать и можете не вспомнить, что заглушили предупреждения

---

> При использовании PHP более устарелой версии возникает ошибка 502

Это ошибка на серверной стороне. Надо смотреть в логи